# 2D Navigation Stack Global Path Planning Method?

Tags: ros, navigation, stack

[image: Rosanswers logo]

With reference to the ROS Navigation Stack: I was wondering which:
a) global path planning method is implemented &
b) which local navigation method is implemented?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/58037/2d-navigation-stack-global-path-planning-method?/) by [mosfet2u](https://answers.ros.org/users/4418/mosfet2u/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2013-03-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The navigation stack uses plugins for the local and global planners.

The [RobotSetup Tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup) describes the basics of how to set up the navigation stack, including how to select which path planners to use.

[base_local_planner](http://www.ros.org/wiki/base_local_planner) and [dwa_local_planner](http://www.ros.org/wiki/dwa_local_planner) can both be used as local planners. They both work similarly, but the code for the dwa_local_planner is much cleaner.

[carrot_planner](http://www.ros.org/wiki/carrot_planner), [navfn](http://www.ros.org/wiki/navfn) and [sbpl_lattice_planner](http://ros.org/wiki/sbpl_lattice_planner) can all be used as global planners.

navfn is fast, but it produces paths with a lot of entropy, which are harder for non-holonomic robots to follow. When configured properly, the SBPL planner can plan for very constrained bases, including non-holonomic and ackermann-type bases.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2013-03-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mosfet2u](https://answers.ros.org/users/4418/mosfet2u/) on 2013-03-19**:
Thanks for clearing that up!